# JavaScript: How can I change the class of a div by clicking another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a `div` appear when I click on another `div`. I was thinking of doing this by using JavaScript to change the class of the `div` when the other `div` is clicked on.

This is the HTML of the `div` I want to appear:

```
<div id="menutext1" class="hidden"></div>
```

This is the HTML of the control `div` (the one to click on to make the above `div` appear):

```
<div id="menu1"></div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }

.unhidden { display: block; }
```

I've looked everywhere and nothing seems to work for me!

I don't have much experience with JavaScript or JQuery but I can understand it.

Thanks in advance :))

Answer (score 0):

.addClass(), .removeClass() should do what you need. .toggleClass() might also be useful. You want to do something like this in your onClick() method:

```
$('#menu1').click(function() {
    $('#menutext1').addClass('unhidden')
});
```

Swap in toggleClass() if you want to be able to hide/unhide. I should add that these are JQuery functions so make sure to include JQuery in your project.

Comment: For OP - while this jQuery must work -- I *HIGHLY* suggest you learn native JavaScript first (and well)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to achieve this:

```
$('#menu1').on('click', function(){
    $('#menutext1').show();
    // OR
    $('#menutext1').toggleClass('hidden unhidden');
    // OR
    $('#menutext1').removeClass('hidden ').addClass('unhidden');
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5vwhvpj2/)**

Note: When working with jQuery and DOM-Manipulation have a look at the [.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function.

---

**Reference**

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without JQuery using the [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) method. And you don't really need the `unhidden` class. When the `hidden` class is toggled off, the div should return to its default display (block).

```
// get the element you want to click on
var controlDiv = document.getElementById('menu1');

// assign a function to run when it is clicked
controlDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // turn the hidden class off or on
    document.getElementById('menutext1').classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```